# create json dynamically in angular js at click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to create a JSON for cart section dynamically in this below format but in my code it does not created.

```
$scope.cart2 = [{
    "image": $rootScope.img,
    "login": $rootScope.login
}, {
    "image": $rootScope.img,
    "login": $rootScope.login
}];
```

My code:-

```
x.controller("first", function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.cart1 = function(x, y) {
        console.log(x);
        $rootScope.img = x;
        $rootScope.login = y;
    }
});

x.controller("cart", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
        $scope.cart2 = [];
        $scope.addd = {
            "image": $rootScope.img,
            "login": $rootScope.login
        };
        $scope.cart2.push($scope.addd);
        console.log($scope.cart2)
    };
});
```

My html:-

```
<div class="cartadd pull-left">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="cart1(x.avatar_url,x.login)">Cart</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to move $scope.cart2=[] empty outside the $scope.getData() function. Because everytime the function is invoked you are initialising cart2 to an empty array

Comment: Ok Thank you so much